# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. PayPal MPL Android

Tags: android, paypal

I'm  Developing and app that process donations, using the MPL of Paypal 
When y call the next code

```
// Use checkout to create our Intent.
Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this,
        new ResultDelegate());

// Use the android's startActivityForResult() and pass in our
// Intent.
// This will start the library.
startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT);
Log.i(TAG, "Executo todo el procedimiento de paypal.");
```

after all the process of payment
1.- Login whit paypal credentials 
2.- Press pay in the next activity 
3.- enter phone number and pin code
4.- Press Create Pin Button

The next error is displayed

```
AndroidRuntime  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3504
AndroidRuntime  E  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5001)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:970)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4168)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10248)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4406)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4349)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7239)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:8847)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3560)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3430)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
AndroidRuntime  E   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
AndroidRuntime  E   at com.paypal.android.MEP.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
AndroidRuntime  E   at com.paypal.android.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
AndroidRuntime  E   at com.paypal.android.c.f$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the text of your TextView within the

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         //set TextView text here.  Because only the UI thread can update UI.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jay Sanyder, the problem is that i don't update any TextView, is the activity in the PayPal_MPL.jar and i don't own the source code.  :D

Answer (score 1):

MPL is deprecated, the new alternative is.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK